# Merge two sqlite database in Windows Metro Apps C#

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-metro

I have two sqlite databases and want to merge all the contents of multiple tables. I followed this article: [Merging two SQLite database files (C# .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544083/merging-two-sqlite-database-files-c-net) But this doesn't work in C# Metro apps/ Windows 8.1/ Windows Phone 8.1 apps. I tried the following code:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection connection1 = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Employee.sqlite");
SQLiteAsyncConnection connection2 = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Customer.sqlite"); 

var result = await connection1.QueryAsync<TableEmployee>("Select Name, Address FROM TableEmployee");

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var EmployeeList = new List<TableEmployee>()
        {
            new TableEmployee()
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                Address = item.Address
            }
        };
            await connection2.InsertAllAsync(EmployeeList);
        }
```

I attempted to solve this by implementing a simple logic as follows:

1. Read all the contents from one table of first database.
2. Next, Insert them all into the next table of another database.

This code snippet reads all the Columns: "*Name*" and "*Address*" from table "*TableEmployee*" of first database "*Employee.sqlite*" and inserts into Table "*TableCustomer*" of second database "*Customer.sqlite*" which have also same two columns "*Name*" and "*Address*".

If there are multiple tables, how to do that? Is there any other way to solve this? Help please!

Answer (score 1):

After huge research I successfully solved this:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection connection1 = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Employee.sqlite");
SQLiteAsyncConnection connection2 = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Customer.sqlite"); 

public async void MergeDatabase()
    {
        string test1 = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\Employee.sqlite";
        string test2 = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\Customer.sqlite";
        await connection1.ExecuteAsync("ATTACH DATABASE '" + test1 + "' AS db1;");
        await connection1.ExecuteAsync("ATTACH DATABASE '" + test2 + "' AS db2;");
        string query = "INSERT INTO db2.TableEmployee ("
              + "Name, Address) "
              + "SELECT Name, Address "
              + "FROM db1.TableEmployee";
        await connection1.ExecuteAsync(query);
    }
```

This code snippet copies all the datas from table *"TableEmployee"* of database *"Employee.sqlite"* to table "*TableEmployee*" of database "*Customer.sqlite*".