# Attach database using SqliteCommand.CommandText

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run a query that involves joining tables from 2 different databases. (**SQLite**)

Note: this is a class library on **.NET Core 2.0**

Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

//Connection string to initial DB
SqliteConnection cnn = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\path\Local\SQLite\DATABASE1.db");
cnn.Open();
SqliteDataReader reader;
SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand();

using (cmd = cnn.CreateCommand()){
    cmd.CommandText = @"
                ATTACH DATABASE 'C:\path\Local\SQLite\DATABASE2.db' AS database2;
                SELECT  act.ID, ap.Name As AppName, au.EmailAddress, et.Name
                FROM database1table1 act
                INNER JOIN database1table2 et on et.id = act.descId
                INNER JOIN database2.table1 ap on ap.ID = act.AppID
                INNER JOIN database2.table2 au on au.ID = act.UserID";

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    // V ERROR occurs here V
    reader = secure_cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
// Do stuff with reader
cnn.Close();
```

In the **C#-environment**, the error I get is:

Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: database2.table1'.

I also have **DB Browser for SQLite** (which is where I initially tested everything). I initially used the GUI to attach ('File' -> 'Attach Database' option), the query works as intended.

But using the SQL editor to attach, when I run:

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'C:\path\Local\SQLite\DATABASE2.db' AS database2;
```

I receive this error:

```
cannot ATTACH database within transaction: ATTACH DATABASE 'DATABASE2.db' AS database2;
```

I've tried setting the attach on a different command.
I've also tried the suggestions posted here: [Merging two SQLite database files (C# .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544083/merging-two-sqlite-database-files-c-net)

Comment: Probably wrong file name.